# PhpStorm how to configure git push to a remote repository?

Tags: git, ssh, phpstorm, digital-ocean

I'm using PhpStorm v8. I've setup git successfully on a local machine. My server is hosted on DigitalOcean; I create a LAMP droplet and install git with success too.

When I try to push git the following window appear when selecting -> `VCS | GIT | PUSH`

[image]

Despite trying different options I don't know what to do in order to setup the remote server in my PhpStorm installation.

I was able to create a Remote Host using SFTP and SSH Keys but the option to define a Remote GIT Host in a DigitalOcean Droplet to push changes is not available.

Answer (score 2):

> The option to define a Remote GIT Host in a DigitalOcean Droplet to push changes is not available.

If you have access to command line on the DigitalOcean Droplet (through an ssh session), defining a remote involves going to the git repo you have defined, and typing:

```
git remote add origin /url/of/remote/repo
```

That means a bare repo exists on the Remote Host though.

Comment: hi @vonc , where do you find the information? I created a repo in my droplet, but I dont know how to access it using phpstorm. do you mean using git remote add origin url/of/... and that will display the master->remote to push the changes?

Comment: @s_h did you create a bare repo or a regular repo (with working tree)?

Comment: @s_h I was looking at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-git-server-on-a-vps